# mandrill into Laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, mandrill

The code that I'm using:

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=***************
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MANDRILL_SECRET=RVk7Ef8CRD-******
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_USERNAME=*************
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_PORT=465
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mandrill'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mandrillapp.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => ['address' => 'rnytt1@mediadigital.no', 'name' => 'ParkogAnlegg Digital Magazine'],
     'encryption'=> env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
     'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
     'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

**services.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'mandrill' => [
        'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET')//zGvUgEUh9E6L2dyN7x7NDg
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key'    => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'stripe' => [
        'model'  => App\User::class,
        'key'    => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],

];
```

I didn't get either the error message or the message for the delivery of the email into my system.

I have same set of the configuration into another application and over-there it's working. But when I migrated same code into this application it's not working here.

Any help would be appreciated!
  Thanks

Comment: stop using Mandrill x_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might miss to work in `config/services.php` file

```
'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET')
],
```